# Magento admin panel backup tool: full system backup fails with no error message

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to use the full system backup in the admin panel backup tool. I'm using it with the "exclude media" option. It shows "Please wait.." and looks like it's working for approximately 45 seconds or so and then that dialog disappears but no backup appears on the list, even after refreshing. The time that it takes until the dialog disappears is shorter than my PHP execution timeout value. There is no error message either. The other backup options (database backup, database and media backup) work fine. What is wrong with the full system backup?

Comment: Use Firebug and its "network" tab to see if you get an error response. If you don't get an error in the response, enable logging in Magento. Check the files var/log/exception.log and var/log/system.log, check the files in var/report/. This should give you further information.

Comment: 10 bucks on a memory_limit error (increase it in php.ini)

Comment: memory_limit set too low, max_execution_time set too short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

1. Clear Cache in magento backend: admin/system/cache (magento/storage/pictures/java)
2. Disable all cache topics
3. clear /var/cache/
4. run backup (system + media)
5. refresh - you will see a new line

magento 1.7.0.2. php 5.2
php: memory_limit: 512MB, max_execution time: 360 secs.